# $λ(Ε_x)\leq 1/2$ prove that $λ({y \in[0,1]:λ( Ε^y)=1})\leq 1/2$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If $E$ measurable subset of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ such that $λ(Ε_x)\leq 1/2$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$, prove that $$λ({y \in[0,1]:λ( Ε^y)=1})\leq 1/2$$.

$λ$: Lebesgue measure

$Ε_x=\{y \in\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\in E\}$

$Ε^y=\{x \in\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\in E\}$

I tried to use the double integral $ \int_{E}1dλ(x)dλ(y)$ and Fubini's theorem to (somehow) get the inequality but I think my idea was wrong, because I only got $\leq \infty$. Then I tried to get something from $λ( Ε^y)=1$. Didn't have any luck either. I miss something. I thought about proving by contradiction but I have no idea how to move from there. Can someone give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A:=\{y\in[0,1]:\lambda(E^y)=1\}$. Suppose that $\lambda(A)>1/2$. Then by Fubini's theorem for indicator functions
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}&\ge\int_{[0,1]}\lambda(E_x)\,d\lambda(x)\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\lambda(E^y)\,d\lambda(y) \\
&\ge\int_A\lambda(E^y)\,d\lambda(y)>\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}